# Switch gnome-terminal with tmux - but completely

Tags: ubuntu, tmux, gnome-terminal

Ubuntu, xorg, i3.

The goal is to have tmux as the default terminal. Easily achieved as the internet is full of great tips like `[[ $TERM != "screen" ]] && exec tmux` in your `.bashrc`.

This works but it seems that tmux always runs as a child. When i'm in gnome-terminal i can press `Ctrl+Shift+T` and it will open a new tab. This shortcut works as well under tmux and i assume that gnome-terminal is its parent? Is this correct?

I'd like to have tmux run on its own. What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by child.

tmux has to run in a terminal.

You can make tmux be the first process in the terminal. You are already doing this by starting it with "exec" so it replaces the shell, but you could also do the same by configuring gnome- terminal to run it directly or by making tmux your login shell.

If you just want gnome-terminal not to capture the key bindings, then you can unbind them in the gnome-terminal config, or use a different terminal that doesn't use the same keys like xterm.

Comment: So tmux is not itself a terminal?

Comment: It is a terminal but it is not an X terminal, it is a terminal that runs inside another terminal. You need an external terminal - in X that will be an X terminal like xterm, gnome-terminal; on Windows it could be putty; or it could be the Linux console. Someone wrote a fork of tmux that IS an X terminal, but it is a bit primitive and I don't know if he still maintains it: https://github.com/dylex/xtmux

Comment: Might I recommend zutty as a replacement for gnome terminal, it's a great match for tmux. gnome-terminal seems like overkill, you'll have tabs in two places.